# Show Date Selected in ASP Calendar on Button Click Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

HI all,
I Have a Asp.net ASP calander and a 2 button on my page on my first button's Text is "**1 Month**" and second button's text is "**1 Year**",Now when I click on the "1 Month" then in my calander the one month later date from now is selected and highlighted with different color, similar when I clik on the  "1 Year" Button now that date is selected in my calander which is after one year come from now.

Comment: What is the problem u r facing?

Comment: I think it might be what he wants to happen, not what is happening...

Comment: I want when I click on the Button then in my calander the date is selected  in Calander which comes after one month/1 year

Comment: the question was so obvious you forgot to ask it :)
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code required to add one month to the selected date.

```
DateTime newDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddMonths(1);
Calendar1.VisibleDate = newDate;
Calendar1.SelectedDate = newDate;
```